# Calling Https Url

Tags: java, url, tomcat, https, jvm

I have written web service and hosted project on server with SSL certificate.If I want to call HTTPS url, I need to import certificate in JVM manually or through program on client side.

I can't ask any client to do extra work on his side before calling my https url, I would loose my credibility.

If any one knows how to deal with this, please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should pay for a real SSL certificate (trusted by one of the common root certificate authorities), rather than getting a self-signed one. Then there won't be any need to important any certificates.

The point about losing credibility with your client is an important one, because that's precisely *why* you need to buy an SSL certificate - it establishes that an element (however weak) of authenticity... you might still be serving up malware or whatever, but there's still a paper trail back from the site serving the content to whoever paid for the SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.I have bought the certificate from AlphaSSL CA organization.